# Interpolating graph in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, interpolation, smoothing, curves

Im trying to plot a graph in gnu plot using this command

```
    plot 'temp.txt' using 1:3 title 'humidity' with lines smooth csplines,

   'temp.txt' using 1:2 title'temprature' with lines smooth splines
```

but the curves are not smooth enough as you can see in the image [image]

I want the curves to be more smooth by interpolating the existing data.

Answer (score 1):

"smooth kdensity" will get you smoother curves, but it won't be from interpolation.  The curves will not go exactly through any of the points.

Answer (score 0):

Your data sampling is probably higher than your csplines sampling. Try `set samples 1000` before the `plot` command.

Comment: I did what you said but it doesn't make the graph smooth

Comment: @Khaadija Post your data file somewhere so that I can test it.